# Filter table with drop down values given multiple constraints

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table that stores drop down list values.
The table looks like this:

```
id | display_text | value | context | special_case
------------------------------------------------------------
0 | X            | x      | Global  | -
1 | a            | a      | Screen1 | No
2 | b            | b      | Screen1 | No
3 | c            | c      | Screen2 | No
4 | d            | d      | Screen2 | Yes
```

I have the following constraints

- Whether or not a value is spl case depends on another table.
- Global is always shown.
- If it's screen1, I show - x, a, b
- if it's screen2, I show x, c
- if it's screen2 + spl case, I show x, c, d

I came up with

```
(
    select
        *
    from
        MY_TABLE
    where
        context = 'Global'
)
UNION(
select
    *
from
    MY_TABLE
where
    context = 'Screen1' and 
    special_case=false
)
UNION(
select
i.*
from
MY_TABLE i,
MY_TABLE_2 r
where
and r.id = 'id'
and i.context = 'Screen1'
and i.spl_case =(
    CASE
        WHEN UPPER( r.cond ) like upper( '%cond%' ) THEN TRUE
    END
)
)
```

Is there a better way to either write the SQL or re-organize my tables?